# 'Kotlin -> Menu item does not show

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a menu item with a icon of a trashcan to delete all items.

Fragment.kt:

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_delete){
        deleteAllGames()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun deleteAllGames() {//function//}
```

When I start my app I don't get errors but It does not show my menu item.

I do have a toolbar.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9PBA.png)

Comment: Did you remember to call [`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) on the `Fragment`?

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you that was the problem